# new downloaded provisional profile installed without App bundle id instead it indicates (*)

Tags: ios, appcelerator, provisioning-profile, appcelerator-studio

I have upgraded my titanium studio SDK from 3.4.0 to 5.3.0 and due to that I did some changes in code to run it in simulator so that I able to Launch IOS Adhoc/Enterprise App. Problem is that when I have downloaded new provisional profile, It creates problem while distributing app. During Distributing my App,it shows me provisional profile which i have manually deleted from  " devices->provisional profile ". And when I go to "Manage settings" to  manually browse new created provisional profile, It fetches that provisional profile with App id as (*). there is no bundle id mentioned in provisional profile. I have also cross checked in my xcode and in xcode it indicates me latest donloaded provisional profile.

Please give me your ideas to fix my problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit unclear. However, if you're unable to find your new provisioning profile in Studio while packaging an app for iOS adhoc/enterprise, then, Go to Appcelerator Studio Preferences: Studio ->Platforms ->iOS -> Provisioning Profiles -> Here you can browse a new provisioning profile if it's not added.

This will automatically appear in the packaging wizard.

Comment: Hi, I am doing exactly as you explained but it gets provisional profile without app I'd instead it gets that provisional profile with apo I'd as (*). So that I can't attach that profile with my app . What should I do for that?